# PubNub chat iOS app doesn't receive Push notification msg

Tags: apple-push-notifications, pubnub, apn

I used PubNub service for chating in my app, and it could work well now, for: subscribe channel, publish msg to channel, receive msg...
But not I want to receive push notification msg when one user send msg to a channel that user subscribeb.
I configured APNS certificate in PubNub admin 
[image]

I tested my PEM file for Push service follow [link](https://support.pubnub.com/support/solutions/articles/14000043600-how-do-i-test-my-pem-key-#latest)

The push msg came.
I added my device token to channels that I subscribed by

```
[self addPushNotificationsOnChannels:@[@"channel1", @"channel2"] withDevicePushToken:self.deviceToken andCompletion:^(PNAcknowledgmentStatus * _Nonnull status) {
    if (!status.error) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Token Chat" message:status.errorData.information delegate:@"Sent token OK" cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
    else {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Token error" message:status.errorData.information delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}];
```

And then, I double checked list channels that the deviceToken was be added again, the list channels are matched.
But when I tried to send (publish) msg from chat (from user to user, user to channel), my device didn't receive any push msg.

I perhap miss some steps or something? Pls advise!

Comment: Have you tried using the pndebug channel to see if there are any error messages?  [Please review this mobile push troubleshooting section](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/mobile-gateway#advanced_troubleshooting_enabling_advanced_debug) and let us know if you get any useful messages from the -pndebug channel.

Comment: @CraigConover Yes, I tested on -pndebug and the msg was came, but when I chat by users on channels, the msg not came

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PubNub Mobile Push Notification Format

As discussed in private support thread, your message:

```
{"data":{"time":1523961017642,"text":"Hello"},"event":"dev-ecteam","sender":"DOAN-dev-ecteam"}
```

...does not include `pn_apns`. In order for PubNub to know that you want to send this as a push notification via APNS, you must include the message inside of `pn_apns` and APNS requires `aps` key (`data` key is required for Android).

```js
{
  "pn_gcm": {
   "data": {
    "time": 1523961017642,
    "text": "Hello"
   },
   "event": "dev-ecteam",
   "sender": "DOAN-dev-ecteam"
  },
  "pn_apns": {
   "aps": {
    "time": 1523961017642,
    "text": "Hello"
   },
   "event": "dev-ecteam",
   "sender": "DOAN-dev-ecteam"
  }
}
```

The entire message will be received by any subscribers that are actively subscribed, but only the contents of `pn_gcm` will be received by Android devices and contents of `pn_apns` will be received by iOS devices registered for push notifications on the channel.

For more information on PubNub Mobile Push Notification, see:

- [PubNub makes it easy to deliver APNS and/or GCM push notifications](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/tech/push-notifications/)
- [Sending APNS and GCM Messages to Subscribers and Mobile Push Notification Services in One API Call](https://support.pubnub.com/support/discussions/topics/14000006344)
- [PubNub iOS SDK Mobile Push Gateway Tutorial](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/mobile-gateway)
- [PubNub iOS SDK Mobile Push Gateway Tutorial](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/mobile-gateway)
- [How can I troubleshoot my push notification issues?](https://support.pubnub.com/support/solutions/articles/14000043605-how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-push-notification-issues-)